# Variadic templates - incomplete type

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++11, variadic-templates

Having this code:

```
template<class ...Args>
struct Are_Same
{
    enum {value = Are_Same<Args...>::value};
};

template<class A,class... C>
struct Are_Same<A,C...>
{
    enum {value = Are_Same<A,C...>::value};//HERE is THE ERROREOUS LINE
};

template<class A,class B>
struct Are_Same<A,B>
{
    enum {value = std::is_same<A,B>::value};
};
```

I'm getting error from gcc 4.6.1:

> error: incomplete type 'Are_Same' used in
>   nested name specifier.

I thought that by doing `Are_Same<A,C...>::value` I will invoke recursive call which at the end will simply expand to `Are_Same<A,B>`. Obviously it's not the case. Anyone knows where am I making mistake?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that the definitions of the templates are wrong, in both cases you are triggering exact recursion. I would have expected the compiler to die with some stackoverflow inside the compiler but a different error is produced...

An implementation of the `are_same` variadic template could be:

```
template <class... Args>                    // base (optional to declare the template)
struct are_same;

template <class A, class B, class... Args>  // recursion
struct are_same<A,B,Args...> {
    static const bool value = is_same<A,B>::value && are_same<A,Args...>::value;
};

template <class A, class B>                 // stop condition
struct are_same<A,B> {
    static const bool value = is_same<A,B>::value;
};
```

Note that in the `recursion` step, one argument is dropped from the list of arguments, so that the new problem to resolve is a *reduced* version of the original. This type of template metaprogramming is quite related to recursion, and the same rules apply, to be able to use recursion you need to ensure that each recursive step gets you closer to a solution. In this particular case, given a list of N potentially same types, each step reduces the problem to finding whether N-1 types are the same.

You can use alternatively, as stop condition (replacing the former one) a degenerate version of the `are_same` problem:

```
template <class A> 
struct are_same<A> {
   static const bool value = true;
};
```

Which is *degenerate* in the sense that it does not really make sense asking whether a single type *are_same*, but for different metaprogramming tasks it could be appropriate.

A different potentially more efficient algorithm (I am not sure whether the compiler will avoid the instantiation of the template in the recursion step above) that does not depend on `is_same` could be:

```
template <class... Args>
struct are_same;

template <class A, class... Args>
struct are_same<A,A,Args...> {              // recursion
    static const bool value = are_same<A,Args...>::value;
};

template <class A, class B, class... Args>
struct are_same<A,B,Args...> {              // cut, A and B are not the same
    static const bool value = false;
};

template <class A>
struct are_same<A> {                        // end of recursion
    static const bool value = true;
};
```

In this case, the compiler will prefer the `recursion` to the `cut` steps whenever the two types are the same, so we need not check `is_same` internally. At the same time, if the compiler goes into the `cut` step, we don't need to process the rest of the type list, as we already know the answer.

Comment: that is freaking brilliant, especially the "short circuit" step. Thanks.

Comment: Nice, but there is a small bug in the 1st code snippet. Should be `static const bool value = is_same<A,B>::value && are_same<B,Args...>::value;`

Comment: @VJo: They are exactly the same, once you have proven that `A == B`, recurring with `<A, Args...>` or `<B, Args...>` does not matter at all, nor will it have any advantage, you are triggering a new instantiation of the template and that at this point the compiler will resolve for whatever the type of `A` and `B` is (i.e. `int`, `double`...), both pieces of code are exactly the same.

Answer (score 3):

I would do it like this :

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream> 

template <class... Args>
struct are_same
{
  static const bool value=true;
};

template <class A, class B, class... Args>  // recursion
struct are_same<A,B,Args...> {
    static const bool value = std::is_same<A,B>::value && are_same<B,Args...>::value;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout<< std::boolalpha << are_same< int >::value << std::endl;
    std::cout<< std::boolalpha << are_same< int, int, int >::value << std::endl;
    std::cout<< std::boolalpha << are_same< int, int, double, int >::value << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: thanks I like the way without stopping condition. Great stuff; +1

Comment: @smallB: This contains exactly the same stop condition, it is just hidden in the general template, there are only two specializations, one for the generic step, one for the stop condition (in this case the stop condition looks *more general* as it is `template <class... Args>` but it will only be the best match for the compiler when it can no longer apply the `recursion` step (i.e. when there is a single type) In my case I prefer making the stop condition more explicit as I hate to think and have to figure out how/when the recursion will stop, but that is just preference.

Answer (score 0):

Probably simplest implementation could be like this:

```
template <typename... TList>
struct are_same { constexpr static bool value = false; };

template <typename T, typename... TList>
struct are_same<T, T, TList...> { 
    constexpr static bool value = are_same<T, TList...>::value; 
};

template <typename T>
struct are_same<T> { constexpr static bool value = true; };
```

Alternatively you can replace stop condition with

```
template <typename T>
struct are_same<T, T> { constexpr static bool value = true; };
```

But the first one is more general because `are_same<type>::value == true`. Another question is what should be `are_same<>::value` equal to. This gives you `false` but it is not a big deal to add one more template specialisation like this.

```
template <>
struct are_same<> { constexpr static bool value = true; };
```